# Gnome 42 on Arch. GUI stalling and Journal is filled with messages : unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user' 'too many open files'

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, dconf

Recently updated to Gnome 42. GUI has become unstable, will lock up after a few hours and journalctl is filled with this error message, which I am unable to find results for:

```
unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user' 'too many open files'
```

There is plenty of space and no permission errors. I have no idea what is causing this issue.

Arch Linux, fully update. Gnome on LightDM.

Thanks in advanced.